# What is the difference between these two declarative content clauses?

Tags: tense, grammaticality, syntax

1. The kids were told that 2 to the power of 3 **is** 8.
2. The kids were told that President Joe Biden **would** visit their school.

Both sentences use the same past tense in main clauses, but use different tenses in that- clauses.

***Why*** does sentence #1 use simple present tense, yet sentence#2 uses a past tense (past future tense)?

Comment: Because it is "Universal Truth". Another example is of Universal Truth is "The teacher taught the students that the sun rises in the East."

Comment: @Man_From_India, Another question" How can I judge whether a sentence tells "Universal Truth"? What is " Universal Truth"? Please make it specific, thanks.

Comment: It is written as "general truth" instead of the term I used. https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/upper-intermediate/unit-2/tab/grammar

Comment: @ Man_From_India, That is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The kids were told that 2 to the power of 3 is 8.

For general truths, the present tense can be used.

- I was told the sky is blue but I don't believe it.

The condition of the sky remains the same. Therefore, *is* is used.

Compare that to:

- I was told the sky was blue. [on that day but not today, for example]

*was/is depends on what a speaker wishes to say.*

**WHEREAS**: The sentence below is reported speech:
The kids were told that President Joe Biden would visit their school.

It works like this: *will* becomes *would* in reported speech:

"Children, President Biden **will visit** our school".   [Actual speech]

The principal told the children that President Biden **would visit the schoo**l. That is reported speech.

Comment: It seems there is quite a difference in usage between the UK and US. Professor John Lawler, an American linguist, told me yesterday that "general truths" wasn't a phrase acceptable to Americans. He also reminded me of searching for grammar rules from recognized and authoritative sources.

Comment: @user421993 may I get a chance to have a look at the discussion between you two? Because I want to know the difference.

Comment: @user421993 **He may express this usage another way**. But the usage is right: a statement using an x is y clause can be used with another in the past tense if **one wants to refer to the permanence of a state or condition**.  As for general truths not being acceptable to Americans, it is you who have misunderstood him. I showed you with my examples how this works. I suggest you reread my two sentences. Finally, there is NO difference between US and UK usage as the point is not grammar: it's semantics.

Comment: @ Lambie, Perhaps you're right. This topic is about semantics, not grammar. But he did state that he didn't accept the phrase " general truths" about which I had showed him the source.

Comment: @user421993 So get the name for it from him.

Comment: @user421993 and Lambie: I guess in the question, sentence #1 can correctly be written as "The kids were told that 2 to the power of 3 is/was 8".  (Not sure but my guess is that user421993 must have heard of optional backshifting).

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes, one can backshift OR not. And the reason is stating a general truth or condition, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical operation is valid in a manner not bound by time. But the visit of the president was, it *would* happen in a specific time, and also it *could* not happen depending on the circumstances.